# Postgresql full text search part of words

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

Is postresql capable of doing a full text search, based on 'half' a word?
For example I'm trying to seach for `"tree"`, but I tell postgres to search for `"tr"`.

I can't find such a solution that is capable of doing this.

Currently I'm using

```
 select * from test, to_tsquery('tree') as q where vectors @@ q ;
```

But I'd like to do something like this:

```
 select * from test, to_tsquery('tr%') as q where vectors @@ q ;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sounds like you simply want wildcard matching.

- One option, as previously mentioned is **trigrams**. My (very) limited experience with it was that it was too slow on massive tables for my liking (some cases slower than a LIKE). *As I said, my experience with trigrams is limited, so I might have just been using it wrong.*
- A second option you could use is the **wildspeed** module: http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/wiki/wildspeed
  (you'll have to build & install this tho).

The 2nd option will work for suffix/middle matching as well. Which may or may not be more than you're looking for.

There are a couple of caveats (like size of the index), so read through that page thoroughly.

Comment: hasn't the wildspeed stuff been part of PostreSQL core since 2008...?

Comment: any answers to the question above?

Comment: wildspeed hasn't been updated since 2008, so unless it's part of the core already I would use the [pg_trgrm](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/pgtrgm.html) extension.

Answer (score 29):

You can use tsearch prefix matching, see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/textsearch-controls.html#TEXTSEARCH-PARSING-QUERIES

```
postgres=# select to_tsvector('tree') @@ to_tsquery('tr:*');
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

It will only work for prefix search though, not if you want partial match at any position in the word.

Comment: That is kind of the direction i'm looking for. But i'm interested in the word(s) that are equal to 'tr:*' (in your example). Is it possible to only get those words back?

Comment: Well, to build on what you wrote, something like SELECT * FROM test WHERE vectors @@ to_tsquery('tr:*') should do it. Or do you mean you want to know which individual words inside the tsvector field matched? I don't think you can do that...

Comment: i  need indeed the fields/words that matched my input.

Answer (score 5):

```
select * from test, to_tsquery('tree') as q 
where vectors @@ q OR xxxx LIKE ('%tree%')
```

':*' is to specify prefix matching.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with trigrams but it's not part of tsearch2.

You can view the manual here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/pgtrgm.html

Basically what the `pg_tgrm` module does is split a word in all it's parts so it can search for those separate parts.