# postgresql tsvector partial text match

Tags: postgresql, match, partial, tsvector

I'm trying to create a PostgreSQL query to find a partial text inside a tsvector column.

I have a tsvector value like this `"'89' 'TT7' 'test123'"` and I need to find any rows that contains "%es%".

How can I do that?

I tried

```
select * from use_docs_conteudo
WHERE textodados @@ to_tsquery('es')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to use fast `ILIKE` queries for wild match. [**`pg_trgm`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html) will be the right tool to go with. You can use [POSIX regex rules](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html) for defining your query.

```
WITH data(t) AS ( VALUES
  ('test123! TT7 89'::TEXT),
  ('test123, TT7 89'::TEXT),
  ('test@test123.domain TT7 89'::TEXT)
)
SELECT count(*) FROM data WHERE t ~* 'es' AND t ~* '\mtest123\M';
```

Result:

```
 count 
-------
     3
(1 row)
```

Links for existing answers:

- [Postgresql full text search part of words](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4551550/3961156)
- [PostgreSQL: Full Text Search - How to search partial words?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9319995/3961156)

Comment: I need to use tsvector to perform a search that contains the argument without a prefix matching. If I have "motorcycle" and I'm trying to search "torc", that would work fine.

How could I do it with tsvector and tsquery?