# Django Queryset icontains() method not returning exact match

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to filter a model, by passing the text query, and checking if any of the fields contains the value that matches exactly or partially to the given text query.

So let's say I have a model named `Sample`, which contains char fields `["name", "state", "type"]`.
Assuming one of the model object has a value of `state` to set as `"barely alive"`

I looked at the methods described in the following django doc:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/search/

I want to retrieve that object by using any of `"barely"`,`"arely"` or `"barely alive"`as a text query.

I initially tried something like `Sample.objects.annotate(search=SearchVector(*list_of_fields)).filter(search__icontains=query_text)`

Above line will however, will not return a correct queryset if I pass a full  text `barely alive` as a query text and only work when partial text such as `barely` or `alive` is passed.

So I then tried 
`Sample.objects.annotate(search=SearchVector(*list_of_fields)).filter(search=query_text).filter(search__icontains=query_text)`
But then it returns an empty Queryset.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL's full text search has quite a few intricacies with regard to partial matching, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539930/postgresql-full-text-search-part-of-words/4551550#4551550) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513501/postgresql-full-text-search-how-to-search-partial-words/9319995#9319995).

However, if you can get by with an `OR` query as you attempted, it's not difficult, you just need an appropriately constructed [Q object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q) instead of two chained `filter` calls (because filter chaining uses `AND`, not `OR`). So instead of

```
.filter(search=query_text).filter(search__icontains=query_text)
```

use

```
.filter(Q(search=query_text) | Q(search__icontains=query_text))
```